# Sudden TypeORM FindConditions type errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

After reinstalling node_modules I am suddenly getting a FindOneOptions/ObjectID error in my NestJS service.

Was building fine minutes ago beforehand.
Makes me wonder, is this a code err or a typings err?

Using "@nestjs/typeorm": "^7.1.5"
Which seems to be using typeorm 0.2.35:
Local installed version: 0.2.35.
Global installed TypeORM version: 0.2.37.

The actual code

```
async getOne(id: number, userId?: string, type?: XPType, currentUser?: User) {
    const options: FindConditions<XP> = {
        id
    };
    userId && (options.userId = userId);
    type && (options.type = type);

    const post = await XP.findOne(options); // <-- error
    ...
```

Here is the actual error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(this: ObjectType<XP>, id?: string | number | Date | ObjectID, options?: FindOneOptions<XP>): Promise<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'FindConditions<XP>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | Date | ObjectID'.
      Type 'FindConditions<XP>' is missing the following properties from type 'ObjectID': generationTime, equals, generate, getTimestamp, toHexString
  Overload 2 of 3, '(this: ObjectType<XP>, options?: FindOneOptions<XP>): Promise<XP>', gave the following error.
    Type 'FindConditions<XP>' has no properties in common with type 'FindOneOptions<XP>'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(this: ObjectType<XP>, conditions?: FindConditions<XP>, options?: FindOneOptions<XP>): Promise<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'import("/Users/bracicot/dev/dev-server/dev-server/node_modules/typeorm/find-options/FindConditions").FindConditions<import("/Users/bracicot/dev/dev-server/packages/server-common/dist/entities/experience-post.entity").XP>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("/Users/bracicot/dev/dev-server/packages/server-common/node_modules/typeorm/find-options/FindConditions").FindConditions<import("/Users/bracicot/dev/dev-server/packages/server-common/dist/entities/experience-post.entity").XP>'.
      Types of property 'userId' are incompatible.
        Type 'string | import("/Users/bracicot/dev/dev-server/dev-server/node_modules/typeorm/find-options/FindOperator").FindOperator<string>' is not assignable to type 'string | import("/Users/bracicot/dev/dev-server/packages/server-common/node_modules/typeorm/find-options/FindOperator").FindOperator<string>'.
          Type 'FindOperator<string>' is not assignable to type 'string | FindOperator<string>'.
            Type 'import("/Users/bracicot/dev/dev-server/dev-server/node_modules/typeorm/find-options/FindOperator").FindOperator<string>' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/bracicot/dev/dev-server/packages/server-common/node_modules/typeorm/find-options/FindOperator").FindOperator<string>'.
              Types have separate declarations of a private property '_type'.ts(2769)
const options: FindConditions<XP>
```

Seems to be related to [4241](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4241) but am not sure. I'm hoping someone can help me understand this.

Comment: what's the type of `XP`? I'm using `FindConditions` type just like you but with custom repositories

Comment: Hey @MicaelLevi it's a class to model the data. Standard data stuff in it such as id, title, and many others. For now I've changed all instances of `FindConditions<XP>` to `any`. No idea what happened here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error:

1. Overload 3 is the one you're attempting, and the one that SHOULD resolve, because it's the only one which includes the `FindConditions` parameter: `(this: ObjectType<XP>, conditions?: FindConditions<XP>, options?: FindOneOptions<XP>): Promise<...>`
2. Digging further, there is a discrepancy between the following:

   ```
   'string | import("/Users/bracicot/dev/dev-server/dev-server/node_modules/typeorm/find-options/FindOperator").FindOperator<string>'
   ```

   is not assignable to type

   ```
   'string | import("/Users/bracicot/dev/dev-server/packages/server-common/node_modules/typeorm/find-options/FindOperator").FindOperator<string>
   ```

   It looks like you have two packages:

   1. `dev-server`
   2. `server-common`

   and that these are including SEPARATE `node_modules/typeorm/find-options/FindOperator` instances, forcing your compiler to regard them as different types. This is backed up by the last error statement; `Types have separate declarations of a private property '_type'.`.
3. Conclusively, I think you should consolidate the node_modules used. There are several ways to do this and I won't suggest which to take, because I think it depends on variables unknown to me. The main two approaches that spring to my mind however are

   1. Using a monorepo tool (I got relevant hits duck-duck-go-ing "monorepo tools") and/or package manager (pnpm, npm/yarn in workspace mode) which solves this systematically for you
   2. Have `server-common` (which sounds like a supporting library) either be the sole includer of the dependencies (specifically, typeorm), or have them be listed as peer-dependencies so that the application including `server-common` gets the say on what types it uses.

   **Edit:**

   3. After a re-read, I also realised that the error occurred `After reinstalling node_modules`, so it's possible that a third option would be to simply ensure a consistent version of typeorm by strictly specifying the dependency without `^`, `~`, or `x` notations using the exact same version in every relevant `package.json` file.

Comment: Wow @Martin Grönlund thank you for such a detailed and brilliant answer.